# Is there an easier way to show why this query is always equivalent to bitor?

Tags: plpgsql

This works, and I can't see right off the bat why:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bitor ( x bigint, y bigint ) RETURNS bigint AS $body$
BEGIN
     RETURN x + y - bitand(x,y);
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
```

I have posted a couple things around SE for [a more mathematical explanation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132827/66648), so I understand why it works logically now (at least in circuitry) but I was curious to post it here as it ultimately started as a query problem. Or maybe, the linked post is already the clearest way to show this?

Comment: I hope you don't use this in pl/pgsql. Postgres has built-in bit operators.

Comment: It's more of a curiosity than something for production, of course

Answer (score 4):

In short, you want to prove that:

```
bitand(x,y) + bitor(x,y) = x + y
```

Split the `x` and `y` numbers into the respective bits. Now, lets prove first that the same stands for bits `a` and `b` (a and b can only have the values `0`and `1`):

```
bitand(a,b) + bitor(a,b) = a + b
```

But for bits these are trivial:

```
bitand(a,b) = least(a,b)
bitor(a,b) = greatest(a,b)
```

Therefore (assuming `a <=b` without any loss of generality):

```
bitand(a,b) + bitor(a,b) = least(a,b) + greatest(a,b) = a + b
```

So, back to `x` and `y` and splitting them:

```
x = a0 * 1  +  a1 * 2  +  a2 * 4  + ... +  an * 2^n
y = b0 * 1  +  b1 * 2  +  b2 * 4  + ... +  bn * 2^n

x + y = (a0+b0) * 1  +  (a1+b1) * 2  +  ... +  (an+bn) * 2^n
```

But we can do the same for bitand and bitor:

```
bitand(x,y) = c0 * 1  +  c1 * 2  +  c2 * 4  + ... +  cn * 2^n
bitor(x,y)  = d0 * 1  +  d1 * 2  +  d2 * 4  + ... +  dn * 2^n

bitand(x,y) + bitor(x,y) = (c0+d0) * 1  +  (c1+d1) * 2  +  ... +  (cn+dn) * 2^n
```

Considering also that:

```
bitand(ai,bi) = ci
bitor(ai,bi) = di
```

we apply our previous results to find:

```
x + y = (c0+d0) * 1  +  (c1+d1) * 2  +  ... +  (cn+dn) * 2^n
```

and we have a proof.

Comment: What I'm worried is possible overflows. It's probably wiser to use `(x - bitand(x,y)) + y` to avoid them.